# Firebase notification on Android yields TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of null

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need help with this error that has haunted me for days:

**sendNotification TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of null
at sender_id.then.fromUserResult(/user_code/index.js:25:48)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)**

```js
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_id}/{notication_id}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const receiver_id = event.params.receiver_id;
    const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

    console.log('Temos uma notificação para: ', receiver_id);

    if (!event.data.val()) {
      return console.log('A notificação foi deletada do Banco de dados:', notification_id);
    }

    const sender_id = admin.database().ref(`/Notifications/${receiver_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');

    return sender_id.then(fromUserResult => {
      const from_sender_id = fromUserResult.val().from;

      console.log('Voce tem uma notificação de:', from_sender_id);

      const senderUserQuery = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${from_sender_id}/user_name`).once('value');

      return senderUserQuery.then(senderUserNameResult => {
        const senderUserName = senderUserNameResult.val();
        const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${receiver_id}/device_token`).once('value');

        return deviceToken.then(result => {
          const token_id = result.val();
          const payload = {
            notification: {
              title: "Notificação",
              body: `${senderUserName} lhe enviou uma solicitação.`,
              icon: "default"
            }
          };
          return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
            .then(response => {
              console.log('Processo de notificação.');
            });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: So `fromUserResult.val()` appears to be `null`. Have you tried logging `fromUserResult`? Why do you `return console.log(`…`);`? You have a typo in `senderUsernameResult` vs. `senderUserNameResult`.

Comment: 'senderUsernameResul't vs. 'senderUserNameResult'.
I fix it here but the problem remains

Comment: So, what about my other questions?

Comment: I tried to log in `fromUserResult` but the print nothing appears, I logged `console.log ('sender:', sender_id);` and
`sender: Promise {
  DataSnapshot {
  node_: 
   ChildrenNode {
     children_: [Object],
     priorityNode_: null,
     indexMap_: [Object],
     lazyHash_: '' },
  ref_: 
   Reference {
     repo: [Object],
     path: [Object],
     queryParams_: [Object],
     orderByCalled_: false },
  index_: PriorityIndex {} } }`

Answer (score 0):

stop and start firebase function and it works, :/